# fullScreenCover appears only when value of isPresented changes

Tags: swiftui

I have an app project on Xcode that doesn't work anymore since I upgraded to Xcode 13. On MyView(), fullScreenCover(isPresented: $myState, content: {...}) does not work when the value of myState is initialized to true before MyView() appears. In other words, when I navigate to MyView(), myState is true whereas fullScreenCover does not appear, but when I add a button that toggles myState and click it twice, fullScreenCover appears. Is there something I didn't get about fullScreenCover() ? Did something change on Xcode 13 or iOS 15 ?

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @State var myState=true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                myState.toggle()
            } label: {Text("toggle mustLearn")}
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $myState, content: {Text("Test")})
    }   
}
```

fullScreenCover doesn't appear when I navigate to MyView() from the MainMenu():

```
struct MainMenu: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink (destination: MyView(), label: {
                Text("To MyView()")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please share the code

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 0):

I think its a matter of when the view is receiving the change of `myState`.
It works if you change from `false` to `true` `onAppear` like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @State var myState = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                myState.toggle()
            } label: {Text("toggle mustLearn")}
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $myState, content: {Text("Test")})
        
        .onAppear {
            myState = true
        }
    }
}

struct MainMenu: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink (destination: MyView(), label: {
                Text("To MyView()")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test it ? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: yes I did. I'll update my answer to the full code.

Comment: Ok it works thanks for your help. But is it normal that I should add onAppear ? Because for my real app it's very problematic. I want this fullScreenCover to appear depending on a variable that changes over time

Comment: then you could publish this var and use `.onChange`

Comment: Thank you! It works now, but I still find it weird that it works this way

Comment: Your NavigationView is missing it’s detail view